# c# Construct <xxx>

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I Just started to evaluate The MS Enterprise Library. They use the following instruct to get instances:

```
var customerDb = 
    EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("Customers");
```

I know GetInstance is the method, but What kind of construct (or struct) `<Database>` is?
is it some kind of generic?

Comment: you should be able to dive in to Database Entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `GetInstance<Database>` is a call to a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx), where `Database` is the type of the generic parameter for the particular call.